# HighCharts not rendering on Polymer page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highcharts, polymer

I am using Polymer in combination with HighCharts for my project.
The code I am using is :

HTML :

```
<div class="container" layout vertical center>
        <paper-shadow z="1" class="span-shadow">
          <post-card id="card1">
            <img width="70" height="70" src="../images/graphex.jpg">
            <h2>Some Graph</h2>
            <div id="container2" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
          </post-card>
        </paper-shadow>
```

and for JS :

```
$(function () {
    $('#container2').highcharts({
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Average Temperature',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com',
            x: -20
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Temperature (°C)'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: '°C'
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            borderWidth: 0
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
        }, {
            name: 'New York',
            data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]
        }, {
            name: 'Berlin',
            data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]
        }, {
            name: 'London',
            data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
        }]
    });
});
```

But while the card is generated correctly, the graph inside it is not visible and I get this error :

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating
>   'HighchartsAdapter.addEvent') (anonymous
>   function)highcharts.js:304:237 (anonymous
>   function)highcharts.js:306:162 global codehighcharts.js:322
>   exporting.js:9

and

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $

How do I fix this error ?

Thanks !

Comment: `$ is not defined` is because of not having jQuery on your page. Use the Jquery script on your page and try again.

Comment: `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: No it is still not rendered. I am now getting an error on the line with $ saying "Undefined is not a function".

Comment: Please use http://jsfiddle.net and put your code in there. save and put the link here for us to see your problem

Comment: Here is the link : https://jsfiddle.net/92brs0qz/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`Highcharts`** is not defined on your page, so put the script of Highcharts on top of your page. Then use:

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container2'
        }
```

instead of:

```
$('#container2').highcharts({ .. });
```

Here's the working [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/92brs0qz/2/)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Highcharts-Chart](https://github.com/avdaredevil/highcharts-chart) which allows you to do the very same thing but manages your dependencies for you.
And also supports data-binding and event support.

For your Problem:

```
<head>
  <link rel="import" href="bower_components/highcharts-chart/highcharts-chart.html">
</head>
<body>
  <template is="dom-bind" id="app">
    <highcharts-chart id="Chart" x-axis='{"categories": [[arr2str(chartInfo.categories)]]}' type="spline" title="Monthly Average Temperature" subtitle="Source: WorldClimate.com" x-label="Months" tooltip-options='{"valueSuffix": "&deg;C"}' on-after-print="getData" y-label="Average"></highcharts-chart>
  </template>
  <script>
    var app = document.querySelector("#app")
    app.chartInfo = {
      categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
      data: [
        {name: "Tokyo", series: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]},
        {name: "New York", series: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]},
        {name: "Berlin", series: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]},
        {name: "London", series: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]},
      ]
    }
    app.arr2str = (arr)=>{return JSON.stringify(arr)}
    app.async(()=>{
       app.$.Chart._chart.xAxis[0].update({categories: app.chartInfo.categories})
       app.chartInfo.data.forEach((el)=>{
         app.$.Chart.addSeries(el.name,el.series)
       })
    },500)
  </script>
</body>
```

And that's it! More examples [here](http://avdaredevil.github.io/highcharts-chart/).

## Edit:

Here's the new more optimized way of doing this:

```html
<base href="https://user-content-dot-custom-elements.appspot.com/avdaredevil/highcharts-chart/v2.0.1/highcharts-chart/">
<link rel="import" href="highcharts-chart.html">
<body>
  <template is="dom-bind" id="app">
    <highcharts-chart id="Chart" x-axis='[[makeCategorical]]' type="spline" title="Monthly Average Temperature" subtitle="Source: WorldClimate.com" x-label="Months" tooltip-options='{"valueSuffix": "&deg;C"}' data="[[chartData]]" y-label="Average"></highcharts-chart>
  </template>
  <script>
    var app = document.querySelector("#app")
    app.makeCategorical = {categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']}

    app.chartData = [
      {name: "Tokyo", data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]},
      {name: "New York", data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]},
      {name: "Berlin", data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]},
      {name: "London", data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]},
    ]
  </script>
</body>
```

**Click Run code snippet to see the chart!**